# Eigenvalues for solving linear recurrence equations

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

After discovering the way to come up with formulas for such sequences as the Fibonacci sequence using matrices it occurred to me this may not necessarily always possible. What might skew one’s endeavor is a case in which one of the eigenvalues is 1, 0 or -1 for then applying the linear transformation repeatedly does not do much to put it mildly. I was wondering if there is a way around this. Is it possible to solve recurrence relations using compositions of transformations even if the above conditions apply?

Comment: Just because one eigenvalue is zero or $\pm1$ doesn't mean all the eigenvalues are like that, so it doesn't mean repeated application doesn't do much. And if all the eigenvalues are zero and/or $\pm1$ then maybe the sequence you're studying doesn't do much. But it would be so much easier to give a satisfactory answer, if you would give an example of a linear recurrence that you find troubling.

Comment: By looking at the solution set, if the characteristic polynomial has $n$ distinct roots, then we could hope to have it in a matrix form. This corresponds to having the matrix being diagonalizable, whence we can find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors. In the more general case (characteristic polynomial has repeated roots), then there are some initial conditions which don't yield a matrix solution.

Comment: Note that x(n+2) = 2x(n+1) - x(n) yields a linear function ax + b where a, b are dependent on the initial conditions. It is not as though this relation produces something that is the same for all n, yet trying to solve this with Binet’s method gives eigenvalues equal to 1. This results in a contradiction since I began with a transformation clearly changing input vectors but at the end I suddenly discover it is not the case. I would not say it is a relation that “doesn’t do much”, but it may suggest it is impossible to represent a linear function with an exponential function.

Comment: I think your issue is with repeated eigenvalues rather than eigenvalues $0,1,-1$.  You would have the same problem with the recurrence relation $x_{n+1}=4x_n-4x_{n-1}$, where the eigenvalues are both $2$.  Here you have solutions like $x_n=2^n+n2^n$.  Note $an+b=an1^n+b1^n$.

Comment: @Calvin, $x_{n+1}=2x_n-x_{n-1}$, characteristic polynomial doesn't have two distinct roots, but the recurrence can still be written in matrix form, $$\pmatrix{x_{n+1}\cr x_n\cr}=\pmatrix{2&-1\cr1&0\cr}\pmatrix{x_n\cr x_{n-1}\cr}$$ Initial conditions have nothing to do with it. To solve, you need eigenvectors and generalized eigenvectors, and you can write the solution in terms of those.

Comment: I don't understand your comment at all, Arthur.

Comment: @GerryMyerson To clarify, while I agree that you can set up the matrix form initially, I was trying to explain that we can't always solve it into just the simple eigenvalues/vectors form and conclude that $ x_n = \sum \alpha_i \lambda_i ^i$ (which is what I thought OP was going for). This is because not all of the eigenspaces have dimension 1, and the dimension 2+ eigenspaces result in terms that look like $ n^k \alpha_i \lambda_i ^n$. That is exactly what tif is going for in his comment.

Comment: So to summarise what I believe is the consensus: When you have repeated eigenvalues you get solutions of the form $\sum_i \alpha_i n^k\lambda_i^n$, and there is nothing unusual about  the case $\lambda_i=1,-1$ - the solutions (including linear terms for $\lambda_i=1$) are of exactly the same form and are obtained the same way.  If you have a single eigenvalue equal to $0$, then again you obtain solutions in exactly the same way as for other eigenvalues.  The only case which you need to treat separately is the case where you have $0$ as a repeated eigenvalue (as $n^k0^n=0$ for $k>0$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the recurrence relation $x_{n+1}=x_{n-1}$ for $n\geq1$, $x_0=a, x_1=b$.  For $n\geq1$ we have:
$$
\left( \begin{array}{cc}0&1\\1&0
\end{array}\right)
\left( \begin{array}{cc}x_n\\x_{n-1}
\end{array}\right)=
\left( \begin{array}{cc}x_{n+1}\\x_{n}
\end{array}\right)
$$

The above matrix has eigenvalues $1,-1$ and the general solution to the recurrence relation is as usual $$x_n=u1^n+v(-1)^n=u+v(-1)^n.$$

Solving for $u,v$: $$u+v=a, \qquad u-v=b,$$
so $$u=\frac{a+b}2, v=\frac{a-b}2.$$

As you can see the fact that the eigenvalues were $1,-1$ did not change anything.

Next consider the recurrence relation $y_{n+1}=y_{n}$, $n\geq1$ with $y_0=a,y_1=b$.

Then for $n\geq1$ we have:

$$
\left( \begin{array}{cc}1&0\\1&0
\end{array}\right)
\left( \begin{array}{cc}y_n\\y_{n-1}
\end{array}\right)=
\left( \begin{array}{cc}y_{n+1}\\y_{n}
\end{array}\right)
$$

Now we have eigenvalues $0,1$ and the general solution has the form: $$u1^n+v0^n=u+v0^n.$$
Solving for $u,v$ (remembering $0^0=1$) we get: $$u+v=a,\qquad u=b,$$
so
$$
u=b,\qquad v=a-b.
$$

Again nothing about the calculation was different.

Comment: If you have $0$ as a repeated eigenvalue, then I suppose the procedure is a little different to other eigenvalues:  If $0$ is repeated $k$ times, then you can regard the sequence as starting from $x_k$, so you do not get $0$ as an eigenvalue.  Then obtain the values $x_0,x_1,\cdots,x_{k-1}$ from the initial conditions.